# Add "Next Desktop Background" to context menu in Windows 11

Tags: windows, desktop, background

I have tried numerous times to add Next Desktop Background Picture to my context menu in new windows 11 to no avail.

Does anyone know ho to get it there permanently?

It shows up when you change themes but it only stays visible until you change the background(s) once they are changed it disappears again (Next Desktop Background)

Comment: That is not a native feature of Windows 11

Comment: What have you tried? We need to know what you have tried so that we do not suggest something you've already attempted. Make your question more clear and complete by editing it.

Comment: Do the themes you are using have multiple pictures and is your background type set to slideshow? The `Next Desktop Background` option only exists when background is a slideshow of pictures.